# Load modules from lodash on demand

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, babeljs

I am using Browserify with Babel and Gulp.
Currently my project requires very few part of `lodash` and i don't want to load whole modules.

```
import assignIn from 'lodash/assignin';
import isPlainObject from 'lodash/isplainobject';
import isFunction from 'lodash/isfunction';
```

Above code is working fine but a bit time consuming that i have to specify whole path repeatedly.
wouldn't it be good if it could be done as:

```
import {assignIn, isPlainObject, isFunction} as _ from 'loadash';
```

and use it as `_.assignIn`. and i can get namespace as `_` too.
Am I doing something wrong there is another way of doing or this is the only way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use the [`babel-plugin-lodash`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-lodash) plugin, it does pretty much what you want.

Instead of:

```
import assignIn from 'lodash/assignin';
import isPlainObject from 'lodash/isplainobject';
import isFunction from 'lodash/isfunction';
```

you can just use:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

and the output from the browserify will be transformed.

For example:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

function Foo() {
  this.a = 1;
}

Foo.prototype.b = 2;

_.assignIn({ 'a': 0 }, new Foo);

_.isPlainObject({});

_.isFunction(/abc/);
```

without the plugin:

```
var _lodash = require('lodash');

var _lodash2 = _interopRequireDefault(_lodash);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
...
```

with the plugin:

```
var _isFunction2 = require('lodash/isFunction');

var _isFunction3 = _interopRequireDefault(_isFunction2);

var _isPlainObject2 = require('lodash/isPlainObject');

var _isPlainObject3 = _interopRequireDefault(_isPlainObject2);

var _assignIn2 = require('lodash/assignIn');

var _assignIn3 = _interopRequireDefault(_assignIn2);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. But still there is something i will be missing.
`lodash` has transformation available, what about other dependencies.